# How do I organize MS Access functions and subroutines into standard modules?

Tags: vba, ms-access, module, standards, code-organization

What are conventions for the grouping of subroutines and functions into standard modules with the MS Access VBE? I can find plenty of information on nomenclature and the function of subroutines and functions within modules, but nothing on *how to group* subroutines and functions into standard modules.

Currently, I have two total standard modules-- one called "Subs" and one called "Functions", each containing hundreds of lines of code that it is becoming a drag to navigate. What guidelines can I use to make it better?

Comment: This question could be primarily opinion based and may get closed as such.  But basically what @iDevlop said in his answer - I have modules grouped.  So one could contain things like `WorkBookIsOpen`, `WorkSheetExists` - generic functions I can import into any project.  Others will have very specific functions - a database I'm working on contains one called `mdl_Functions`; these are just small functions (with extra lines for error handling) which returns specific information from the database - `GetStatusID`, `GetTeamID`,`GetRequiredStaff`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks so much for your feedback, @Mat's_Mug and @iDevlop. Your respective abstract explanation and more concrete response both moved me toward the answer I was looking for. 
It seems like both of you are suggesting, too, what my fruitless googling before asking this made me suspect, and what @Darren_Bartrup-Cook alluded to above-- there is no formal structure for organizing modules, and appropriate structure can very widely from one database to another. Correct me, please, if my takeaway is wrong, but what I've gleaned from what both of you have said is that the general principles to pursue are:

- to find groupings that are meaningful and useful within your own code (better to risk grouping too small than too big, maybe?)
- to keep implementations at a high level of abstraction, for the readability/ease of debugging the code

Answer (score 0):

I try to keep **reusable** Subs and Functions appart from application specific ones.
I try to group those by functionnality. This way I have a module I can import when dealing with text files import/export, another one for XML stuff, another one for browsing files or folders, extracting the folder from a full path and so on.
Also, I generally export modules to .bas files (right click on module, then Export) which I can reimport in other apps.

Answer (score 0):

What you're after, is called *abstraction*.

It doesn't matter at all that a member is a `Sub`, a `Function`, or a `Property` (please don't say you have a `Properties` module...). What you care about is *its purpose*.

Name things for what they're used for, and regroup public members by *purpose*. Keep the public members' implementations simple, at a relatively high *level of abstraction*.

In plain English, this means if you have a procedure that makes coffee and fetches a mug, knows where to get the water, the milk, the cream, the sugar, the hazelnut and French vanilla aromas, knows how much to pour of everything, stirs it and serves it (or whatever it is that you do in *hundreds of lines of code*), then you have a procedure that's doing way too many things.

Split it up. Break it down into small steps, each more specialized (i.e. at a lower abstraction level) than the previous.

```
Public Sub MakeCoffee()

    Dim selectedCoffeeType As CoffeeType
    selectedCoffeeType = PickCoffeeType

    Dim selectedSize As CoffeeSize
    selectedSize = PickCoffeeSize(selectedCoffeeType)

    GrindGrains selectedCoffeeType
    Infuse selectedCoffeeType, selectedSize
    AddExtras

End Sub
```

Notice this `MakeCoffee` procedure couldn't care less about whether there's water in the machine, or whether milk needs to be lathered, whether there are cups of the selected size available, whether there's grains for the selected type, how much sugar and/or cream to pour in, or about any other irrelevant details: it lets you pick a type and a size, and uses that information to do its deed.

The details are at a lower *abstraction level*, implemented under that procedure, in `Private Function` and `Private Sub` procedures. They're underneath it, because they're closely related, and if you read the module top-to-bottom, it's telling you a story that goes from very high-level to very specialized and detailed - there's never a need for a 200-liner procedure.

Now another module comes along, and you need a vending machine that sells chips and colas (or bio sandwiches and bottled water). Same thing: *abstraction* determines how things split up.

Then you need the coffee machine to implement a payment functionality. Are you going to copy the existing code from the vending machine? Call into the vending machine's private procedures from the coffee machine's code? Luckily you can't do that. No, you'll *extract a class* and encapsulate the payment module functionality into its own specialized object, and both the coffee and the vending machines can use it.

And if you use [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com), then you can put `@Folder` annotations in each module, and actually organize your modules into folders and sub-folders that you can browse with the add-in's *Code Explorer* feature - so you have absolutely no reason to fear having "too many modules".